# Messaging library for jeroMQ

Tags: json, message-queue, zeromq, jeromq

I have chosen jeroMQ for building Asynchronous message channel for publishing content from multiple clients. On the other end server side workers processes request and notify client only if server wanted to notify client based on the message received.

On digging deep, looking for messaging library to marshal/un-marshal message. I found kvpmsg class which does the job for simple key-value.

Don't want to re-invent the wheel if some standard library exists, that can be applied for bigger objects

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are asking for data serialization libraries. Check Wikipedia for [a list and a comparison of data serialization formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats).

Also there is a [relevant entry in ZeroMQ FAQ](http://zeromq.org/area:faq#toc4) explaining why ZeroMQ doesn't include any serialization format:

> **Does ØMQ include APIs for serializing data to/from the wire representation?**
>
> No. This design decision adheres to the UNIX philosophy of "do one thing and do it well". In the case of ØMQ, that one thing is moving messages, not marshaling data to/from binary representations.
>
> Some middleware products do provide their own serialization API. We believe that doing so leads to bloated wire-level specifications like CORBA (1055 pages). Instead, we've opted to use the simplest wire formats possible which ensure easy interoperability, efficiency and reduce the code (and bug) bloat.
>
> If you wish to use a serialization library, there are plenty of them out there. See for example
>
> - [Google Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)
> - [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/)
> - JSON-GLib
> - C++ BSON Library
>
> Note that serialization implementations might not be as performant as you might expect. You may need to benchmark your workloads with several serialization formats and libraries in order to understand performance and which format/implementation is best for your use case (ease of development must also be considered).

Comment: Got bit dragged and posted question after having a look at this page. My objective is to send a key-value. But the value is a list of integers. One solution is, convert list to comma separated string and then bring back list on the server side with typical tokenizing and parsing. I wanted avoid later part ie., parsing.

Comment: Yes, inventing your own serialization format is an option I forgot to mention :)